# Passing a complicated object from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I need to pass a rather complicated data structure from C# to a native C++ function. This is a structure, which besides of simple data types like `int`s and `string`s, also contains arrays of other structures, containing arrays of other structures ... and so on, up to 3 or 4 levels deep. My initial idea was to use pinned pointers, but now I'm starting to doubt that it was a good idea. The code is messy and I'm keeping a large number of objects pinned for a long time. I have to say that the C++ code can take many hours to finish.

Now to my question. Would it be a good idea to use google's [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) to serialize the data structure in C#, put it inside a continuous memory buffer and then deserialize it in C++?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [Marshal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to allocate and write data into your complex structure. For instance you can allocate a buffer using [AllocHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s69bkh17%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then use the various copy and write functions to write data into this buffer using whatever memory layout you desire. This allows you to keep your C++ code unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a common serialization/deserialization, such as XML. Of course, some methods, such as XML serialization, will only serialize the public properties of your objects, so choose appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You got a few options.

COM, managed C++, binary serialization and marshalling. I'd go for managed C++ if portability was not an issue. And second - binary serialization. Easier to maintain.

So yes, protocol buffers is definitely a viable solution.

Comment: I cannot use COM and managed C++, because the code is supposed to run on Linux too.

Comment: Then binary serialization is the only sane option. Go for protocol buffers, mate.